# How to use multiple table returned from stored procedure in another stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I got stored procedure returning 2 tables. I use the information from both in my c# in Visual Studio 2010 without any issue.

Now my problem is, after doing the work at C# side, I want to update all the fields in the results with new date, using a brand new update stored procedure. For that, the easiest theoretical way would be to call the same stored procedure and use the returning tables in my update statement.

Unfortunately, that's where my problem starts. In the front end, all I gotta do call `ds.Table[0]` and `ds.Table[1]` (assuming results were stored in `ds`), to access each returned table, but I don't know how to access the multiple tables returned from the stored procedure, in another stored procedure.

For example (really simplified version), this was used in first stored procedure:

```
Select distinct 
    CTE.SSN, CTE.LastName, CTE.FirstName, CTE.MiddleI
From (Table 1)

Select distinct 
    CTE.SSN, CTE.AddressID, CTE.AddressLine
From (Table 2)
```

So 2 different tables were returned, both OF WHICH I can easily accessed in front end to do my work. However, now I want to update using the SSN in both tables which are returned by my previous stored-procedure. So all I gotta do, is use the results from the previous stored-procedure in my new update stored procedure (I do not want to send the ssn from c# to sql). However, I do not know how to access multiple tables returned from stored procedure! If my stored procedure was returning only 1 table, it would be peace of cake, but that's not what is happening!

Like to thank you for reading such long post :)

Comment: refactor using a table-valued function to contain the main logic.

Comment: **What** concrete database? Almost all RDBMS speak *SQL* as their query language - but things like stored procedure are **highly** vendor-specific, so it really matters whether you're using Oracle, Sybase, Postgres, SQL Server, MySQL, Interbase or something else - please **update your tags** accordingly! Thanks

Comment: Its Microsoft Sql 2012